# Error when running jekyll docker container with boot2docker on Mac

Tags: docker, jekyll

I am running docker on my MBP (Yosemite 10.10.3) with boot2docker (v1.6.2). When I try to run `docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/src" grahamc/jekyll build` (without sudo) I got the following error:

```
twer$ $(boot2docker shellinit 2> /dev/null)
twer$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/src" grahamc/jekyll build
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find coffee-script-source-1.9.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:37:in `require_from_bundler'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:16:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bundle/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine on my machine:

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/src" -p 4000:4000 grahamc/jekyll serve -H 0.0.0.0
Configuration file: /src/_config.yml
            Source: /src
       Destination: /src/_site
      Generating...
     Build Warning: Layout 'nil' requested in atom.xml does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'none' requested in feed.xml does not exist.
                    done.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/src'
Configuration file: /src/_config.yml
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

My best guess is that you have a `Gemfile` in your source code.

Comment: Thanks @davix, you are right. I have a Gemfile in my source code. It works well locally. The code is forked from https://github.com/mmistakes/hpstr-jekyll-theme . I am new to Ruby, but I think I should be able to run `bundle install` to install the gems. But that gives the same error.

Comment: I have also tried with a clean jekyll site and it's working fine.

Comment: you cannot do a `bundle install` and then use `jekyll` image to run it, since `jekyll` will not load your gems.

Comment: I have [a blog](http://mrcoder.github.io/run-jekyll-with-docker/) about the Dockerfile I am now using, just in case someone else comes across a similar issue.